# best way of inserting my stock array data into database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

My array is given (stock data) :
struction of my_data = [date, (price:volume), ..., (price:volume)]
For example

```
my_data = 
["2022-12-01", (2000:157),(2005:5), (2010:23654), (2050:132)]
["2022-12-02", (1990:4),(2000:123)]
["2022-12-03", (2010:11),(2005:12100),(2050,342)]
["2022-12-04", (2080:1230),(2090:55),(3010,34212354),(3050,29873)]
```

As you see, the dimensions of (price:volume) are arbitrary.

What is best way of creating database whose data array is like above ?

Comment: How are you trying to do it and what don't you like about it?

Comment: In general you will probably want to look at [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). It is not as difficult as it seems and it gives you good guidelines on how to define tables in relational databases.

Comment: To wwii, I am looking for day-volume distribution based on 1minute OHLC :).

Comment: Hey, Juhuja. I will also look at  database normalization(I don;t know yet). Thanks a lot bro !!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table this way.

| date | price | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | 2000 | 157 |
| 2022-12-01 | 2000 | 5 |
| 2022-12-02 | 1990 | 4 |

This allows you to query based on the date individually, so you can easily filter a day's records or records in between a range of dates.

Comment: Just a small fix: I think you meant to write date instead of data in the table headers.

Comment: Thanks, DG. I will try to do it what you suggested.